# Jena/maven/eclipse issue - MultiException[java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry

Tags: eclipse, maven, jena

I have a Java maven project that has a jetty plugin and uses different dependencies in the pom.xml file. Jena is one of them. based on what I've read online, dependency to jena tbd would be sufficient as it also bring its dependencies which include core, arq, etc. When I do that and build the project, it works fine but as soon as I start debugging, the following is the error I get. I have tried switching between java 7 and 8 versions and still no luck fixing the issue. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but it's very frustrating to be stuck at the first step of implementing the project. Without Jena dependencies the project does what it is supposed to do but as soon as the Jena dependencies are added and the Jar files are downloaded. The errors appear upon debugging.

Any ideas? Appreciate it.
(I've excluded many of the classes that the system can't load from jena jar files here due to limited words here... there are so many errors!).

```
MultiException[java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry org/apache/jena/iri/IRIRelativize.class from jar file:/C:/Users/amis/.m2/repository/org/apache/jena/jena-iri/3.1.1/jena-iri-3.1.1.jar, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry org/apache/jena/iri/impl/SchemeSpecification.class from jar file:/C:/Users/amis/.m2/repository/org/apache/jena/jena-iri/3.1.1/jena-iri-3.1.1.jar]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
2017-01-05 12:47:50.969:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2017-01-05 12:47:50.999:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@625a9c5d{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8585}
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

Comment: Is this the first error? What has this got to do with Eclipse?

Comment: Hi guys I've found the solution for it. Might be useful if others face the same issue. I realised I was using Java 1.7 for the entire application whilst the Jena 3.1.1 requires Java 8. So I used an older version of Jena, 2.13.0 and since it works with java 1.7, the entire thing worked! Thanks for those who spent time to respond. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use at least Jetty 9.2 for the Java 8 code (which Jena 3.x is) to work properly.

Details here: https://webtide.com/jetty-9-2-0-released/

Alternatively, you can try to fix ASM only (I recommend against that): https://vaskoz.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/fix-jetty-9-1-for-jdk8-annotations/

P.S. Eclipse IDE has nothing to do with the fact that Jetty is an Eclipse project (https://eclipse.org/jetty/).

Comment: berezovskiy, the problem was mismatch between java versions. Thanks for your tips.